# AVD stopped working, Process Finished with exit code 1

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

after doing all kind of google, still fail to start my AVD

done all sort of existing suggestion and answer from stack overflow

It was working like charm, but had to format my OS (installed same which I was using) and installed same Android Studio but failed...

**0 - Error I Am Getting**

```
Emulator:Process Finished with exit code 1
Emulator : CPU acceleration status: Unable to open HAXM Device: Error_File_Not_Found
Emulator: Error: x86 emulation currently required hardware acceleration!
```

**1 - Android Studio 3.0**

```
 SdK (H:\Android\SDK)
 Studio (H:\Android\Android-Studio)
```

**2 - Gradle 4.1**

Offline (H:\Android.gradle)

**3 - Windows 7 Professional SP1**

**4 - System Variables**

```
_JAVA_OPTIOMS = -Xmx1024M
ANDROID_SDK_HOME = H:\Android\AVD
```

**5 - AVG Free AntiVirus**

```
Unchecked - Enable Hardware Assisted Virtualization
```

**6 - Haxm_Check**

```
VT Support - Yes
NX Support - Yes
```

**7 - BIOS**

```
Secure Boot - Disabled
Intel HT Technology - Not Supported
Intel VT-x Technology - Supported
Intel Virtualization Technology - Enabled
```

**8 - Windows Uninstall Program**

```
Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager - Installed
```

Please Help Friends, I am Stuck

---

Comment: which version of intel HAXM are you using? @user9543272

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version HAXM version 7.2.0, uninstall it and install version 7.1.0. Doing this will solve your problem.

[Link for version 7.1.0 windows edition of intel HAXM.](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/download/v7.1.0/haxm-windows_v7_1_0.zip)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all your help
Problem is Solved

if your are using windows 7 x64 SP1 (any build or any flavor) and having /dev/kvm or HAXM error

**follow this steps**

1. uninstall HAXM
2. install -
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=46148
3. Reboot - must
4. install HAXM from SDK manager
5. Reboot - must

Comment: which version of intel x86 HAXM are you using?